# Few Featured Images are not Showing after Migrating to Wordpress From Blogger

Tags: wordpress, blogger, migrating

I successfully migrated from Blogger to wordpress by using blogger importer plugin

my new site where i upload my database has new domain name

Problem is.. Some of the feature images are showing but rest of all
is not showing..

Comment: check for the image url.. i want to know which images are you using wordpress hosting or blogger image..?

Comment: Blogger images... They are showing in each and every post but not set as feature in wordpress

Comment: what is your url? are you asking feature image for post or home page slider?

Comment: i am asking you about feature image that shows when you visit a blog homepage and every post contains feature image and title of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may happen that Blogger Importer Plugin skipped importing those images.
To fix this problem you can use [Cache Images by Matt Mullenweg](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cache-images/).

Install this plugin and Go to **Tools** > **Cache Remote Images**.

Click **Scan**.

Now you should see a list of images that are hot-linked from different servers.

Hit the **Cache from this domain** button and Cache Images plugin will start importing images from those hot-linked domains.

Comment: Thanks for your help... all the missing images backed up by using your recommended plugin
But Feature images didn't appear automatically.. no problem
i will do it manually.. THANKS again!